# how do i write textarea value if the condition is true

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

how do i write textarea value from $repvalue value if the condition is true please help me.

```
<html>
    <body>
    <form action="find4.php" method="post" name="finrep">
    <p>Find: <input type="text" name="fin">Replace: <input type="text" name="rep" >
    </p>
    <p><br/>
    <textarea name="comments" cols="25" rows="5" value="<?php echo $repvalue; ?>"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="submit1" value="submit">
    </p>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
    <?php
    if ($_POST['submit1'])
    {
    $findval = $_POST['fin'];
    $textboval = $_POST['comments'];
    if($findval == $textboval){
    $repvalue = $_POST['rep'];
    }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: what happens when u press submit? is there any errors?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Close, but for a `textarea` you actually place the text between the tags, like this:

```
<textarea name="comments" cols="25" rows="5"><?php echo $repvalue; ?></textarea>
```

Also, you may want to clean the value of `$repvalue` with [htmlenitites](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) before outputting it, as any `</textarea>` tags in the variable will break your page.

And as per charlietfl's comment you need to make sure your definition of `$repvalue` needs to be before you try to output it (nice catch, didn't even look at that).

Comment: also need to define `$repvalue;` before try to `echo` it

Answer (score 0):

You must put the textarea value in between the tags

```
<textarea><?php echo $repvalue; ?></textarea>
```